# Binding variable on redux dispatch ActionCreator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have an array of promises, and I'm trying to push new promises into that array inside of another dispatch.then function, but it appears that the array is always out of scope

```
load(params, auth) {
    return dispatch => {
        const { passage, versions, language_tag } = params
        let promises = []

        versions.forEach((id) => {
            // get the version info, and then pass it along
            dispatch(ActionCreators.version({ id: id })).bind(promises).then((version) => {
                promises.push(dispatch(ActionCreators.passages({
                    id: id,
                    references: [passage],
                    versionInfo: {
                        local_abbreviation: version.abbreviation,
                        local_title: version.title,
                        id: version.id,
                    },
                })))
            })
        })
        // 
        promises.push(dispatch(ActionCreators.configuration()))
        promises.push(dispatch(ActionCreators.byRef({ language_tag })))

        console.log(promises.length)
        return Promise.all(promises)
    }
},
```

I've tried a few different approaches, such as setting `var that = this` right before the dispatch inside of the versions loop, and what is shown here, trying to use `.bind(promises)` on the dispatch.

promises.length is always 2, (because of the two that are actually getting pushed at the bottom). I can console statements inside of the `.then` so I know it's getting executed, but the dispatches are not ending up in the promises array.

I could very well be thinking of the dispatch function in an incorrect way.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since you're adding the promises on `then()`, you have already returned the array by the time you're adding the promises. So they do get added, but too late.

Instead, try this:

```
load(params, auth) {
  return dispatch => {
    const { passage, versions, language_tag } = params;
    let promises = [];

    versions.forEach((id) => {
      // get the version info, and then pass it along
      promises.push(dispatch(ActionCreators.version({ id: id })).then((version) => {
        return dispatch(ActionCreators.passages({
          id: id,
          references: [passage],
          versionInfo: {
            local_abbreviation: version.abbreviation,
            local_title: version.title,
            id: version.id,
          },
        }));
      }));
    });
    //
    promises.push(dispatch(ActionCreators.configuration()));
    promises.push(dispatch(ActionCreators.byRef({ language_tag })));

    console.log(promises.length);
    return Promise.all(promises)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. the dispatches are all now being pushed, except that it's saying that `version` in the passages dispatch is undefined. I tried to `.bind(version)` as well.

Comment: Don't bind anything because it doesn't work. The code above clearly assumes that version is what the first action creator's promise resolves to. That probably isn't the case. So look in `ActionCreators.version` for the problem. Make sure it returns a `Promise` and make sure that the promise resolves to the expected version object.

Comment: actually I was wrong in saying that version is undefined, it was something else in a view file! This works great, thank you!